# Mapping unit square to (0, 1)

Tags: algorithm

In general, I am looking for an algorithm that (efficiently, hopefully) maps any point in the unit square (i.e. (0, 1) x (0, 1) to the (open or closed) interval (0, 1).

More specifically, my problem is as follows: given 2 points in 2D, how can I find an ordering between them (i.e. one goes before the other) that is

- commutative
- does not involve "special" cases or testing floating point numbers for equality

One possibility that springs to mind is a space-filling curve such as Morton or Hilbert, but I can't seem to find the description for the continuous case (only for discrete potints) and I'm sure there must be an alternative.

Comment: Commutative, or transitive?

Comment: This sounds more like a math problem that a programming problem. Computers don't have continuous numbers, they just have floating point approximations.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, so I could be wrong, but intuitively I don't think this is possible with continuous numbers.

Comment: If all else fails, recall that (finite, non-NaN) floating point numbers are just a large but finite set of specific rational numbers, and hence the discrete case *is* ultimately applicable.

Comment: @Warren Dew The algorithm should return the same ordering no matter which point goes into it first.

Comment: Alright, I know that floats are just an approximation, but in any case I need an algorithm for that and I think that there exists one.

Comment: @Delnan do you have an algorithm for that? Given that I need to represent all floats (double precision) as integers than, I would guess I need a rather inefficient approach

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "the same ordering no matter which point goes into it first"?  If you mean that (.25, .5) should map to the same value as (.5, .25), then you don't really have an ordering at all.  If you mean f(point1) < f(point2) => f(point2) > f(point1), I think that's implied by a mapping.  If you mean f(point1) < f(point2) => f(point2) < f(point1), again, that's not an ordering.

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing algorithm, which is probably because this is an unusual thing to do. Using IEEE 754 it should be possible to map the floats in [0;1] to 53 bit integers with relative ease by extracting the significand (and possibly special casing 0.0, 1.0 and such), then you could use any of the space-filling curves you mentioned (which is very time- and space efficient even for very high resolutions). But I just noticed you don't seem to have *any* requirements on the order, can't you just use lexicographic order? That is, `(a, b) < (c, d)` if `a < c` or `a = c, b < d`?

Comment: @Warren Dew What I mean is that if f(a, b) and f(b, a) should return the same ordering, i.e. both a < b or b < a

Comment: @delnan Lexixographic ordering needs the test for equality which I would like to avoid. If you omit the test, on the other hand, you lose the commutative property in case values are equal. But I like your idea on using a space-filling curve for the float representation. However, I am not fully convinced if you have special values to consider... Is E. G. 0.0 or 1.0 really encoded differently?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke: Surely you mean antisymmetric, rather than commutative. It's not clear to me whether you're talking mathematics or concrete floating point representations. I would think that the simplest theoretical bijection is to interleave the bits of the (infinite) binary representations of the numbers, which is some kind of space-filling curve. You could do that with the actual bit-representations of the numbers, but since the actual representations are a known length, you could just concatenate, which is easier. In both cases, you'd start by reinterpreting (not casting) to integers.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke You'd have to dig through IEEE 754 to check, I'm not sure, I believe they are encoded differently. Actually lexicographic ordering can be implemented without using the words "equality" (just test <, >, else). The result is the same. Any aversion to equality tests needs reasons, since the usual reason (countering inaccuracies *in prior calculations* by allowing for a tolerance in "equality") does not apply: You'd have the same problem for *any* comparison that takes all of the floats' bits into account, and the fix (round to some amount of digits) is the same regardless.

Comment: @rici those were the solutions I was thinking of, but I just couldn't grok the use of "commutative" here.  "Antisymmetric" would make a lot of sense, though, as you say.  Perhaps Michael could confirm that he actually means "antisymmetric".

Comment: @delnan: 0.0 is coded as all 0s (with the possible exception of the sign bit). 1.0 has all 0s in the fraction. So do 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc; the only difference is the exponent itself. Approximately one-half of floating point numbers have an absolute value of less than 1. Positive floating point numbers can be reinterpreted as integers without changing the meaning of comparison operators.

Comment: @rici Quite likely. I thought floats were normalized to 0.xyz... but now I recall it's *1*.xyz... which makes the conversion I was talking about (0.0 -> 0, 0.0+epsilon -> 1, 0.0+epsilon+epsilon -> 2, ..., 1.0 -> roughly 2^53) rather more complicated. All the more reason to favor one of the "hacks" (reinterpretation, lexicographic comparison), unless OP has a *good* reason to avoid that.

Comment: @delnan: It makes the conversion trivial, but the conversion is to a 62-bit number, not a 53-bit number. (Half the representations are negative, and of the positive ones, half are greater than 1.0. So (leaving out NaNs) a quarter of the representations represent numbers in `[0, 1.0)`. For non-negative numbers, reinterpreting the representation as an integer does not change the order, as I said; all the resulting integers are positive, and the smallest one is 0. So the rest of them must all be less than 2^62.

Comment: if you all are interested in a true bijection or points on a line segment ⇔ points on a square, see this article: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4010/infin2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since computers can not represent continuous numbers, we ultimately have to stick to the discrete case (no matter what number representation we are using).

Lets assume the "unit interval" consits of $N$ numbers. Then the "unit square" consists of $N^2$ discrete elements.

Practically this means we need twice as much bits for representation of elements of the unit square.

That essentially means that concatenation of x and y coordinate will do the job.
Which in fact yields a discrete serpentine type space filling curve.

Since the mapping is bijective, the well ordering of the discrete unit interval directly also translates to a well ordering on the unit square.

The point is, that in *any* case you need twice as much bits and it always comes down to a bit combination in *some* way.

I am not really sure if that is what you had in mind. Maybe you yourself are not so clear about what you want/need?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `double`s or any other type used by computers to mimic read numbers that has a finite set of values you can get - you cannot get a [*bijection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) from `(0,1)x(0,1)` to `(0,1)` - there isn't one, since `|(0,1)x(0,1)| > |(0,1)` for this case.

One lossy solution is to use the average of the two elements: `f(x,y)=(x+y)/2` - but of course, as expected - there will be clashes between different values (it cannot be avoided).

However, if you are dealing with real numbers (the 'real' `(0,1)`), you can.

Each real number `r` can be represented by an **infinite vector** from the alphabet `{0,1,...,9}`. <sup>1</sup> So, you can create a new vector which is interleaving between the different digits:

for example:

```
r1=0.3360000... r2=0.518000....
f(r1,r2) = 0.3531680000....
```

If you want `f((x,y)) == f((y,x))`, you can simply "sort" each pair, and put the smaller element first. For the above example, you will get:

```
f(r1,r2) = 0.3513680000....
```

Note that this solution has clashes as well, to avoid it - you can introduce a new function `g()`:

```
g(3i) = min{r1[i], r2[i]}
g(3i+1) = max{r1[i],r2[i]}
g(3i+2) = r1[i]<r2[i] ? 0 : 1
```

For the above example, this will give you:

```
g(r1,r2) = 0.351132681002002.....
```

---

(1) or any other alphabet with 2 or more characters in it